# Write a function called strLetterCount which accepts a string and returns a new string with each letter and its count in the string

Tags: javascript

Write a function called strLetterCount which accepts a string and returns a new string with each character followed by the number of times it appears in the string. The characters should be returned in the same order as the string with each unique letter followed by the number of times it appears in the string.

My code so far is:

```
//write function format with argument
    function strLetterCount (str){
      //initialize var to hold results for charAt
      let charAt = '';
      let count = 0;
      for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        str.charAt(i);
        results = str.charAt(i);
        for (let j = 0; j < str.length ; j++){
          if(str[i] === str){
            count++
            results = str.charAt(i) + count++
          }
        }
        return results;
      }
    }

    strLetterCount('taco'); //'t1a1c1o1'

    //function should pass a string as argument
    //loop through the string and if a new char is entered store that 
    //loop through string again and count num of new char
    //returns a new string push charAt and numOfOcc
```

It should return the output of 't1a1c101' , however, I am only getting it to loop through the string once and return the first value of 't' but it's not counting the occurrences? I cant identify where to change my logic to hold the count of occurence?

Comment: the `return` in the `for i` loop guarantees the "loop" will run at most once ... that's how return works

Answer (score 1):

I guess you try to achieve something like this.

Each letter will appear in output string with the same number of occurence as in the input string. I'm not sure that's what you want, but that's the thing the *strLetterCount* function intends to do.

```
function strLetterCount (str){
   let results = ""

   //initialize var to hold results for charAt
   for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
   {
      // Get current char and store it into the results
      // We will add the count in a second loop
      let charAt = str.charAt(i)
      let count = 0

      results += charAt

      for (let j = 0; j < str.length ; j++)
      {
         if(str.charAt(j) === charAt)
         {
            count++
         }
      }

      results += count
   }

   return results;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The code was able to run successfully and I really appreciate the pseudo code; it helped me understand what I was missing better!

Comment: How do can I accept the answer? I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: There's a 'check' thing (like a v) next to the answers which you can click on. When it turns green it means you accepted that answer. Hope that helps

Comment: How would you get rid of the duplicate characters? For example: if you had the word "woof" how would I get w1o2f1 as opposed to w1o2o2f1?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't need a count of each letter to be in the same position it started in, i.e. "started" can equal "s1t2a1r1e1d1" instead of "s1t2a1r1t2e1d1", than this should do the trick.

```
function strLetterCount (str){
    // create an object to store each letter
    const countObj = {}
    // iterate over the string
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        // if the letter isn't stored in the object, add it with a count of one
        if (!countObj[str[i]]) {
            countObj[str[i]] = 1;
        } else {
            // if the letter is already in the object, increment the count
            countObj[str[i]]++;
        }
    }
    // create a string to add the letter / count to
    let outStr = "";
    // iterate over the object to create the string
    for (const letter in countObj) {
        outStr += `${letter}${countObj[letter]}`;
    }
    // return the string
    return outStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would satisfy the requirements

```
  function strLetterCount(str) {
        // split the string to array
        let strArr = str.split("");
        // new array without duplicate letter
        let strArrWithoutDuplicates = strArr.filter((value, idx, arr) => arr.indexOf(value) === idx);
        let retString = "";
        // loop through the "strArrWithoutDuplicates" array to find the number of times
        // each elemet appears on the original array
        strArrWithoutDuplicates.forEach(letter => {
            retString += letter;
            retString += strArr.filter((value) => (value === letter)).length;
        });
        return retString;
    }

    let a = strLetterCount('taco'); //'t1a1c1o1'
    console.log(a)
```